# How could I weave two class files using AspectJ - ajc?

Tags: aspectj

I want to weave two class files  using AspectJ - ajc, i.e. I want to implement byte code weaving.

Hello.class     //it is a java class file

AspectHello.class   // it is a aspect class file

How can i implement it on command line?

Thanks in advance

yang

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ajc-ref.html

Answer (score 0):

So it should be something like:

```
ajc -inpath <path to Hello.class> -aspectpath <path to AspectHello.class> -d <path of output directory>
```